# automatic go to another link HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

```
<script>
   
    const TIME_LIMIT = 60;
    let timePassed = 0;
    let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
    let timerInterval = null;
    let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
    
    startTimer();
    
    function onTimesUp() {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
    }
    
    function startTimer() {
      timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
        timePassed = timePassed += 1;
        timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
        document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
          timeLeft
        );
        setCircleDasharray();
        setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);
    
        if (timeLeft === 0) {
          onTimesUp();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
 
    </script>
```

If i want to make after the times is up it direct to another link automatically.
what should i do?
I want to do something at the java script onTimesup funtion.

Comment: is it like below answer, use below code in your function

Comment: Do you really want a JavaScript solution for this?

Comment: no, as long it can automatically go to another file like "./sample"

Answer (score 0):

you can try like to below, to go to other page automatically

```js
setTimeout(function(){
location.href="./sample"
} , 2000);
```

this function will go auto go to page after 2 second, please comment if query.

Comment: how about something like "/sample"? is it possible?

Comment: yes possible, is "sample" folder or file

Comment: it is a file. so if i want to change it into that file it will go like this? setTimeout(function(){
location.href="/sample"
} , 2000);

Comment: is should be "./sample" like this , add dot

Comment: what is the meaning of the function()?

Comment: this allows you to time the execution of a certain function .